# Добавить php-код к декстоп приложению

Tags: php, html, electron

Разрабатываю декстопное приложение на html,js с фреймворком электрон, хочу добавить PHP для связи с БД.

Нужно как-то реализовать, чтобы при попытке авторизации php конектился к локальной БД и забирал/вставлять данные из/в неё.

Сейчас при попытке авторизации, открывается страница с кодом.

[image: Открывается при попытке авторизации]

Comment: У Вас есть три варианта. Правильный - разместить php код и базу где то в интернете и дальше просто обращаться к ней. Вариант два - поставлять вместе с приложением php интерпретатор, сервер (nginx/apache) и базу. Третий вариант - забыть о php, я думаю, что электрон предоставляет какие-то инструменты для доступа к базе.

Comment: @KoVadim комментарий вполне достойный быть ответом. Лично я назвал бы "правильным" третий предложенный вариант, со ссылкой на https://www.npmjs.com/search?ranking=popularity&q=mysql

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо большое

Comment: @KoVadim, а не подскажешь, как можно реализовать первый вариант?

Comment: Берите любой пример, как использовать PHP и разместить в интернете это, скорее всего нужно будет купить хостинг. А дальше с электрон приложения делаются http запросы. И все.